# Matlab Textscan Cell in Cell?

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have a little problem. I know how to avoid it, but I'm not sure is the best.

```
String = textscan('Hello_World','%s','delimiter','_')
```

This returns a {1x1 cell} with a {2x1 cell} in it:

```
String =
{2x1 cell}
```

What I want requires an additional command:

```
String = String{1}
```

which yields what I want:

```
String = 
'Hello'
'World'
```

I would be glad if anybody has a good tip.

Comment: This is the documented behavior. From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#zmw57dd0e761624): `For each string conversion specifier in formatSpec, the textscan function returns a K-by-1 cell vector of strings, where K is the number of times that textscan finds a field matching the specifier.` You can remove a level of nesting using `String = [String{:}];`

Comment: Other alternatives (`regexp`, `strsplit`, etc.) could potentially work 'better', but it depends on your actual application.

Comment: You are right strsplit is the better alternative for my problem, thanks.